# How to call API from controller Laravel without using curl and guzzle as its not working

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, guzzle

How to call an API from a controller using a helper in laravel without using curl and guzzle because both returing nothing. I have tested in postman the api is working fine but not in laravel. 
I need to call several API's from different controllers so what would be a good way to do this? Should i build a helper?

I used curl but it is always giving me a false response.

EDIT:

I am looking for a reliable way to make api calls to various url's without having to rewrite the sending and receiving code for each api I want to use. 
Preferably a solution that implements "dry" (don't repeat yourself) principles and would serve as a base for any api specific logic, (parsing the response /translating for a model). That stuff would extend this base.

Comment: So, why not write some code for that? There is not one "best way" to do that

Comment: @NicoHaase yes but where I mean I need a helper so where I should create a helper for that.

Comment: @MahendraPratap there is no best place for helpers in laravel. I always place them in App\Helpers

Comment: What do you mean by "where"? Have you tried looking up that topic? Using Google, I find tons of tutorials - and if they don't match your use case, you should clarify why

Comment: @NicoHaase I searched but what is best practice for that.

Comment: Best practise is what works for you. Next best practise are the ways others are describing - what have you found so far, why are you struggling with the stuff you've found?

Comment: I have modified the question now this should be reopened because it is no more sounds opinion-based question.

Answer (score 37):

### Update For Laravel 7.x and 8.x. Now we can use inbuilt Http(Guzzle HTTP) client.

docs:: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

$response = Http::post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', [
    'title' => 'foo',
    'body' => 'bar',
    'userId' => 1
]);

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'token' 
])->post('http://example.com/users', [
    'name' => 'Akash'
]);

$response->body() : string;
$response->json() : array|mixed;
$response->object() : object;
$response->collect() : Illuminate\Support\Collection;
$response->status() : int;
$response->ok() : bool;
$response->successful() : bool;
$response->failed() : bool;
$response->serverError() : bool;
$response->clientError() : bool;
$response->header($header) : string;
$response->headers() : array;
```

### For Laravel < 7 you need to install Guzzle pacakge

docs: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/index.html

### Installation

```php
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

### GET

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'); 
return $response;
```

### POST

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$body = [
    'title' => 'foo',
    'body' => 'bar',
    'userId' => 1
]; 
$response = $client->post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', ['form_params' => $body]); 
return $response;
```

### Some Usefull Methods

```php
$response->getStatusCode(); 
$response->getHeaderLine('content-type');  
$response->getBody();
```

- we can also add headers

```php
$header = ['Authorization' => 'token'];
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('example.com', ['headers' => $header]);
```

### Helper For this Method

we can create a common helper for these methods.

- Create a Helpers folder in app folder

```php
app\Helpers
```

- then create a file Http.php inside Helpers folder

```php
app\Helpers\Http.php
```

- add this code in Http.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use GuzzleHttp;

class Http
{

    public static function get($url)
    {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->get($url);
        return $response;
    }


    public static function post($url,$body) {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->post($url, ['form_params' => $body]);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

- Now in controller you can use this helper.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Helpers\Http;

class Controller extends BaseController
{

    /* ------------------------ Using Custom Http Helper ------------------------ */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        $data = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        $posts = json_decode($data->getBody()->getContents());
        dd($posts);
    }


    public function addPost()
    {
        $data = Http::post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', [
            'title' => 'foo',
            'body' => 'bar',
            'userId' => 1
        ]);
        $post = json_decode($data->getBody()->getContents());
        dd($post);
    }
}
```

### Without Helper

- In Main controller we can create these functions

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{

    public function get($url)
    {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->get($url);
        return $response;
    }


    public function post($url,$body) {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->post($url, ['form_params' => $body]);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

- Now in controllers we can call

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function getPosts()
    {
        $data = $this->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        $posts = json_decode($data->getBody()->getContents());
        dd($posts);
    }


    public function addPost()
    {
        $data = $this->post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', [
            'title' => 'foo',
            'body' => 'bar',
            'userId' => 1
        ]);
        $post = json_decode($data->getBody()->getContents());
        dd($post);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further how this code can be used in a good way to query multiple APIs in multiple controllers, still following DRY?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your suggestion. sure i will ad more well explanation

Comment: Still, that only looks like a tutorial about how to use Guzzle to me. The initial question about how to provide the **best way** to use multiple APIs in multiple controllers is still open. Should this code be copied to each individual controller?

Comment: @NicoHaase i edited my answer as you suggested